# Saving CSS of Angular element

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, mouseevent

I am trying to change the CSS of an element during mouseover using custom directives (just for practice!):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="m1">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr custom-tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
      </tr>
      <tr custom-tr>
        <td>Hi</td>
      </tr>
      <tr custom-tr>
        <td>Bye</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  <script>
    var m1 = angular.module("m1", []);

    m1.directive('customTr', function()
    {
      var d={};
      d.restrict = 'A';
      var oldStyle = null;
      var newStyle = {'color': 'red'};
      d.link = function(scope, element, attr)
      {
        if (!oldStyle)
        {
          oldStyle = element[0].style;
        }
        element.bind('mouseenter', function(){
          element.css(newStyle);
        });
        element.bind('mouseleave', function(){
          element.css(oldStyle);
        });
      }
      return d;
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

The changing behaviour is working, but what I want is to revert the CSS back to what it was originally.  For that I am trying to save the CSS state in a variable and then reassigning to this variable later.
But it is not working properly (the last two rows behave as expected but the first row does not change CSS on `mouseleave`).

Also, an error is being generated:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'length' of object '#<CSSStyleDeclaration>'
```

Can anyone tell me how to correctly save and reassign the CSS of an element?

Comment: any reason why wouldn't use `ng-style` or `ng-class` instead?

Comment: @Daniel_L For practice of angular directives.

Comment: you don't have to suffer through parsing css rules. include all the rules you want in your css file and use `ng-class` to *very easily* switch styles.

Comment: I know that there are easier ways to do this, but I want to do in this way only (for learning purpose).

Comment: ok then why not assign your style declaration in your directive to `ctrl.style = 'color:red;'` and then in your controller append that using `ng-style`

Comment: I don't want to get into controller to do this. I believe that the CSS can be changed through the way I want to do, but am not getting the method names correct or some other minor mistake.

Comment: try `angular.element(element)` in your link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365428/cant-change-css-style-in-angularjs, also according to that question the args for your `css` method need to be two strings, not an object literal