# what will element.css('none') in angular do

Tags: css, angularjs, infinite-scroll

I came across element.css('none') while going through source code of [infinite-scroll](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/blob/master/src/infinite-scroll.js). Can someone please help me understand the use of element.css('none') [here](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/blob/master/src/infinite-scroll.js#L51) in the source code ?

Comment: It is for the toogle purpose.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365428/cant-change-css-style-in-angularjs

Comment: @geminiousgoel can you please provide more details ?

Comment: @ManikandanVelayutham how this link is relevant to my question ?