# Angular - CSS properties of added class not showing

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm appending a childitem `div` to another div inside the same angular component. Then I assign a class to it. (using class list) It succesfully inserts the element and also adds the class to it but non of my css class properties are applied to it.

If I add the element manually inside my html code (including the class attribute) the element is shown correctly.

Why is this happening?

Typescript code:

```
let parent = document.getElementById('playingfield');
        let cactus = document.createElement('div');
        cactus.classList.add('cactus');
        parent.appendChild(cactus);
```

HTML code of manually inserting the div:

```
<div class="cactus"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't change CSS style in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365428/cant-change-css-style-in-angularjs)

Comment: sorry wrong tag. I need a solution for normal "Angular" not angularjs. It doesn't find the `angular.something` keyword. Or why doesn't it find the `angular.somthing` methods?

Comment: Why are you adding a `div` element in typescript and not using `*ngIf` in your html template? This looks like bad code style to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To apply the runtime css into your html you need to use **:host** feature of angular.

In your `.css` or `.scss` file set css by this way.

```
:host ::ng-deep .cactus{
    // Your css hear
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! For those interested in what this feature does, see: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

Comment: Thanks! I was looking everywhere and couldn't find an answer