# css is not a function on existing element in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, element

We have a piece of code that suppose to manipulate an existing element.

It looks like this:

```
[this.box] = angular.element('#pop-box-' + this.$scope.$id);
this.box.css({...});
```

Debugging this, the box is found properly and it is the right element. However, I am getting an error that `css` is not a function.
Based on the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element, the element should have that available.

In our case, jQuery is also in the project.

What am I missing?

Comment: can you put your relevant code in stackblitz fork and post link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs

Comment: what this braces for? `[this.box]`

Comment: @LuninRoman It is a destructuring assignment, it extracts the first element from an array, see: https://www.deadcoderising.com/2017-03-28-es6-destructuring-an-elegant-way-of-extracting-data-from-arrays-and-objects-in-javascript/

Comment: Did you try the same code but without destructuring?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365428/cant-change-css-style-in-angularjs

Comment: @LuninRoman I did. Same result

Comment: Guys, thanks for the help.I did need to use the element from `angular.element` as is. I must have had so many changes that is was all messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your element in $()

```
$(this.box).css({...});
```

Comment: Post your Code please